# Transformer design and calculations

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, converter, magnetics

I am trying to find correct way of determining the transformer parameters.

I provided a simple schematic of a PSFB (phase-shifted full bridge) converter below.

1. How do we determine thr primary inductance in the first step and the secondary inductance?
2. What is the exact formula or method to calculate turns ratio?
3. How to determine the number of turns? (The method I follow for the number of turns is Lp x I = N x B x Ae.)

[image]
Source: [Power Topologies Handbook](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ug/slyu036/slyu036.pdf)

Comment: Mhan, If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> *How do we determine primary inductance in the first step and secondary
> inductance?*

Well, the [linked paper](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ug/slyu036/slyu036.pdf) tells you how to choose the secondary inductance (see section 18.1): -

[image]

You can't choose the primary inductance until you have chosen a ferrite core-set. So, take a stab at the core-set that is potentially top of your list and figure out how many turns you need to avoid core-saturation due to too much flux density (aim for a maximum of 200 mT is my advice). Of course you have to leave enough "winding room" for the secondary. This is normally an iterative process.

> *What is the exact formula or method to calculate turns ratio?*

Section 18.1.1 gives strong hints and a formula: -

[image]

I'd aim for a full-load duty cycle at the lowest input supply voltage of a few percent short of 50%.

> *How to determine the number of rounds ? (The method I follow for the
> number of turns is Lp x I =N x B xAe).*

When you say "rounds" I believe you mean turns. This actually goes back to my answer to your first question (choosing the number of turns and core-set to avoid saturation) but, a simple method uses this formula B = V/(4 N f A). Set B to be 0.2 teslas (as per what I mentioned earlier on). "f" is the switching frequency, "A" is the cross sectional core area and, V is the peak voltage on the transformer primary.